# Loading WPF Resources more than once

Tags: wpf, winforms, xaml

I am working in WPF and WinForms for both Windows XP and Windows 7/10 users (.NET 4.0 due to XP).

Some WPF Windows are used as dialogs for older WinForms applications without a WPF Application class/App.xaml file.

This in itself isn't a problem but I find I'm having to declare styles in resource dictionaries in user controls/windows in the WinForms/WPF situations which isn't normally necessary in plain WPF applications due to App.xaml.

My question is whether WPF detects that the same resource is being loaded twice (in a pure WPF application e.g. UserControl and App.xaml) and copes with/manages this without interference from me or do I have to try to ensure I only declare resource dictionaries once?

Many thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer is no.

If you load a resource dictionary as a resource for a usercontrol then each instance of the usercontrol means another instance of any resources it uses in memory. 
If that is going to be a problem then you need to do something.
You might just be able to instantiate an application object and use that to stash your resources in. Application.Current.Resources is after all just referencing the current application.  Depends on exactly how your app works.

Comment: OK thank you for the clear answer.

I need to work on a way for WPF Windows/Controls to work within WinForms applications where I don't have the standard Application object to work with.

Answer (score 0):

If you try to load the same resource dictionary twice, the application will throw a runtime error.
But, if you are only defining the styles already present in the resource dictionary, in the user control also, i.e, basically two styles with the same name one in the resource dictionary and the other in the user control, then no error is thrown. The style in the user control will have a higher priority.

Comment: If I use this (below) xaml in both App.xaml <Application.Resources> and in any user control <UserControl.Resources> (or Window) I never get a runtime error:

<ResourceDictionary Source="pack://application:,,,/myassembly;component/styles.xaml"/>

Comment: You can instantiate and merge a resource dictionary as many times as you like.  A resource dictionary is just a wpf object.  It doesn't error if you new up another instance of one, no more than if you new up another instance of Window1.  I don't follow what Shivani has in mind with that runtime error stuff.